# Single Envelope with Single Document - Multiple Recipients with custom emailBlurb

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending an Envelope using NodeJS with 1 document to multiple recipients for them to sign the document.  I know that using emailBlurb I can have customized email text.  Is it possible to have emailBlurb for each recipients instead of envelope.  Here is the sample JS code.

```
"recipients" : [{"email": email1,
               "name": name1,
               "recipientId" : id1,
               "userType": "sometype",
               "emailBlurb": "Text specific to this recipient",
               "tabs": {
                 "signHereTabs": [{
                   "xPosition": "xx",
                   "yPosition": "yy",
                   "documentId": "1",
                   "pageNumber": "1"                                         
                 }]
               }
             }, 
             {"email": email2,
               "name": name2,
               "recipientId" : id2,
               "userType": "sometype",
               "emailBlurb": "Text specific to 2nd recipient",
               "tabs": {
                 "signHereTabs": [{
                   "xPosition": "xx",
                   "yPosition": "yy",
                   "documentId": "1",
                   "pageNumber": "1"                                         
                 }]
               }
             ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a unique message in the email per recipient.  You can use the `note` property in your recipient definition JSON.  You're allowed a maximum of 1,000 characters on it.

For example-

```
"recipients" : [{
    "email": "jon.doe@test.com",
    "name": "Jon Doe",
    "recipientId" : "1234",
    "note" : "This note will be only be seen by Jon Doe",
    ...
```

Here's the [signer recipient page](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm) in the API docs which explains the property more.